# Controlled reorganisation of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape, cat, reorganize

This is a noob question I guess, but I want to reshape a 3D matrix in a way that the planes of the 3rd dimension are arranged consecutively on the 1st dimension. The idea is that given a matrix A(720x360x120) I can reshape it into a 86400x360 matrix. Using **reshape** doesn't work as it just seems to arrange the numbers consecutively. I can just do it in tests using **cat**:

Being A_test (4x3x2)

```
B_test=cat(1,A_test(:,:,1),A_test(:,:,2));
```

But doing that 120 times is a bit too much. I thought I could use a for loop for it, but I don't quite see how.

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks in advance

Maria

Comment: How about `reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),[],360)`?

Comment: Thank Divakar!! it worked..:-)...it was silly, wasn't it? it's such a relieve to have this working, it had me stuck for far too long!!

Comment: That's okay, we are only learners at different stages of our lives !:) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!! I might actually need that luck..;-). All the best!!